# Replaced my guitar E string. Now tuner shows Hi E instead of E

Tags: guitar, acoustic-guitar

Beginner Here. My acoustic guitar E string broke. I replaced it with another E string that ordered online.

I use Android App for tuning guitar. Now, the tuner shows Hi E, instead of E for this new string.

Did I use wrong string or I replaced it incorrectly? Why doesn't it show normal E?

Comment: There are two E strings on guitars. Which are you asking about? Fat or thin?

Comment: See if you tuner has a manual mode and not auto. This will allow you to choose which string you are tuning and reduce confusion. Many free apps will have this feature. Just remember to put it back in auto or select the next string after.

Comment: Even though you're a beginner, it will be good for you if you didn't rely, like so many do, on a little machine that supposedly tells you the information you need. They're not foolproof, so why not start using your own ears, and get the idea of what each string sounds like in comparison to the one below. There are plenty of googlable examples of how to tune a guitar by comparison with 5th and 4th fretted strings. It'll set you up as someone who actually knows what tuning a guitar is all about. Serious comment.

Comment: Not much information here, I'm hoping the online vendor didn't send you a high E string to replace the low E string, you might wish to check the string gauge of the new string against the old string gauge.

Comment: @Tim It is the thin one.

Comment: @b3ko Yes, I have just tired it manually. Results are the same.

Comment: @skinnypeacock There is nothing written about low or high E on the package of replacement strings. It is just E. And its measurement is 0.010 inch or 0.25mm.

Comment: The GuitarTuna app also shows https://youtu.be/ISWjq_4suLM?t=90 as High E. Is it high E?

Answer (score 2):

Tuners don't always detect the right octave very reliably.   Tune it to whatever E it thinks it is.

It might recognise it as low E if you pluck it a bit further from the bridge, or with a softer bit of your finger.   But it doesn't really matter.  It's not as if you're REALLY in danger of tuning it a full octave high, is it!

Comment: Just make sure you don't miss by an octave; OP is a beginner, and some beginners make that mistake. +1

Comment: Bit of vague info from OP, but yes, there is a danger of tuning a string an octave higher. Seen it happen, and no, it didn't break - itself or the guitar. We guess it's the low E that's been replaced, but it's only a guess. And if it is actually tuned to high E, it's defying the laws of physics!

Comment: I guess if the 'Hi E' display was a surprise, it must be low E.